# Target specific files that include text in a particular directory?

Tags: php, image, directory

I have the following php code below which is randomising the header images on page load.

```
<?php
function displayBackground() {
global $site;
global $dirimgpth;

$dir = 'uploads/product-images/' .$dirimgpth. '';
$cnt = 0;
$bgArray= array();

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    $pathToFile = $dir.$entry;
    if(is_file($pathToFile))
    {   
        if(getimagesize($pathToFile)!=FALSE)
        {
            $bgArray[$cnt]= $pathToFile;
            $cnt = $cnt+1;
        }
    }   
}   
$myRand = rand(0,($cnt-1)); 
$val = $bgArray[$myRand];

}

closedir($handle);

echo($val);
}
?>
```

This all works fine which is great, but the directory I am getting the images from has several hundred image files containing thumbnails and large images.

I would like to change the code above to target the directory folder but only get image files with specific text of "-header.jpg" in the filename.

The directory folder contains files like the following:

1. doors.jpg
2. windows.jpg
3. aluminium-thumb.jpg
4. window-header.jpg
5. conservatory-header.jpg
6. tiled-thumb.jpg
7. roof-header.jpg

The outcome I would like is so the random header only outputs images "4,5,7" from the above list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $entry is your file name you can check if it contains "-header" in name or not like this.

```
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
   if (strpos($entry, '-header') !== false) {
     $pathToFile = $dir.$entry;
     // follow with your code
   }
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it now works to how I wanted it too. Much appreciated

Comment: Great!!  Also as @Marcin Orlowski said, the code you wrote will have performance penalty as number of files increase in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

> This all works fine which is great, but the directory I am getting the images from has several hundred image files containing thumbnails and large images.
>
> I would like to change the code above to target the directory folder but only get image files with specific text of "-header.jpg" in the filename.

Since these JPGs are not changed/added/removed so frequently as I assume, you can safely create static array (updated when you add/remove image), containing all the filenames of your choice and then simply pick random entry from that array.

> The outcome I would like is so the random header only outputs images "4,5,7" from the above list.

you need [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) but again - this is wrong approach due to performance penalty.

Additionally your current code is even more painful, because you seem to not only scan the folder but also read image dimensions. This is wrong, because you just need this for the image of your choice, not all of them.